# How can I re-fetch the revisions of a newly specified branch with git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I've fetched a whole repository from SVN up through revision 15000. I realized that I had an extra branch stashed away in a different location. Is there any way to update the .git/config file with the location of this new branch and re-fetch only the revisions pertaining to that branch?

Answer (score 13):

You can add another `branches` entry to the `svn-remote` section of your `.git/config` file.  After that, running `git svn fetch` should pull down the extra revisions.

---

If I understand correctly, you can force git-svn to rescan older revisions of branches by removing (or changing) the `max-branchesRev` line from `.git/svn/.metadata` and running `git svn fetch` again.  If you change the line instead of removing it, then you'll want to set it to a revision earlier than when your branch was created.  It'll then re-scan the branches for all revisions after that.

---

I probably should've gone with `git svn reset` first instead of messing with `.git/svn/.metadata`.  If the following doesn't work, then I'm out of ideas. :)

```
# Find the svn revision git knows about that's just previous (or close to)
# the revision which created the branch
$ git svn reset -r $foundSvnRev
$ git svn fetch
$ git reset --hard $remoteBranch
```

Then you should be able to use `git svn` as per normal.

Comment: This worked but only pulled the revisions *after* the 15000 I'd already fetched. It didn't crawl the previously fetched revisions for commits to that branch.

Comment: I tried setting the max-branchesRev line in the .git/svn/.metadata file back to the revision just before the branch was created. Then I re-fetched with git svn fetch. Unfortunately, when I check out the branch, the only reivision I see is that one *after* the 15000 that I initially fetched and that I fetched after changing the .git/config file.

Do I need to run git svn rebase in the branch or something? Can I just delete the remote branch, set the property again and re-fetch?

Comment: You could try a `git svn rebase`, but I don't think that will work.

Comment: What about `git svn reset` back to the revision before the branch was committed?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I describe in the last update to my answer.

Comment: Hmm, now my master branch only shows a single commit - the latest one to that remote branch. But the remote branch still doesn't have all the earlier commits. Going to just do a re-import.

Comment: With git-svn I've nearly always have had to re-import. On top of it all, the aggressive ancestor find seems to work differently if done on a subset of revisions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just another place in the same repository, you can simply specify through the --branch parameter. It will ignore anything that was fetched already.

If it's another SVN repository, you can set up another SVN remote and fetch from there.

Comment: Right, but will it consider past revisions (*before* 15000) when invoking git svn fetch? This is an older branch.

Comment: `--branches` is only used for the initial clone/init command.